# Different Thymeleaf layout decorators based on different Spring Securirty roles

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, thymeleaf

I have two user roles and a layout page for each, and a single `.html` which has layout fragments with the main content, accessible by both users. I want to use the specific layout page depending on the user.

This is what I'm trying to do:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
    xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
    xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/extras/spring-security"
    layout:decorate="~{(hasRole('ADMIN') ? adminLayout : customerLayout)}">

<head>...</head>
<body>
    <th:block layout:fragment="someContent">
        <h1>Same main content but replacing layout depending of the user!</h1>
        ....
    </th:block>
</body>

</html>
```

But I keep getting errors of failed evaluation of the page or that the `hasRole` method doesn't exist, depending of the syntax that I try:

```
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1004E: Method call: Method hasRole(java.lang.String) cannot be found on type org.thymeleaf.spring5.expression.SPELContextMapWrapper
```

Is it possible to determine the layout decorator used based on the authenticated user role inside the `.html` file (not in the Controller, etc)? Or rather, is it possible to access these security methods from a scope like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must refer to the utility bean provided by spring security for thymeleaf to be able to call spring security methods.

Invoking spring security methods is done in the method `expression` which is provided by the utility bean and it's return type is boolean. So your code will be like:

```
layout:decorate="~{#authorization.expression('hasRole(''ADMIN'')') ? 'adminLayout' : 'customerLayout'}"
```

Comment: I had to put a `${}` around the expression, but it worked, thanks!

Comment: For future users, here's what @g-otn meant `layout:decorate="~{${#authorization.expression('hasRole(''ADMIN'')') ? 'adminLayout' : 'customerLayout'}}">`